# PHP: Global Variable across PHP blocks

Tags: php, include, global-variables

How do I defined a `global` variable that I can use across blocks of code?

In my case, I need to declare my `global` var within an included header.php and then I need to be able to use it within another included file.

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to access it anywhere since it changes. And it's not sensitive information... just a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the global keyword to modify the [variable's score](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). It doesn't matter if you reference the variable in a file that is included, you just need to use the `global` keyword.

**In header.php:**

```
$var = 'Something';
```

**In included_file.php:**

```
function a()
{
    global $var;
    echo $var;
}

echo $var; // Will print 'something'

a(); // Prints 'Something'
```

Alternatively, you can use the [$GLOBALS](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) array.

Finally, if it's static and not going to change, you can [define constants](https://www.php.net/constants):

```
define('MY_NUMBER', 10);

echo MY_NUMBER; // Outputs 10
```